# How to time a vimscript execution?

Tags: vim

I try to compare two versions of a same vim function. How can I time them and compare?

What I'm looking for is a simple way to benchmark the first version of the function against the second one, with some kind of precise time echo.

Thank you!

Comment: `reltime()` was mentioned below.  See also `:h profile` and `:h 'verbose'` (and `:h 'verbosefile'`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simple demonstration of the use of `:help reltime()` and `:help reltimestr()`:

```
function! Foo()
    " do your thing
    for i in range(1,8)
        let @a = i
    endfor
endfunction

" save current time
let start_time = reltime()

" call your function
call Foo()

" echo elapsed time expressed in seconds
echo "elapsed time:" reltimestr(reltime(start_time))
```

It should output something like:

```
elapsed time:   0.000165
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use `:Time` which is provided by Tim Pope's [scriptease.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) plugin. Scriptease provides some nice tools for vimscript and plugin development.